# App Engine and slow response time

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

We need to build a web service which must alway reply within 100ms. We plan to use memcache as our storage system to avoid latency from Google Cloud SQL or DataStore.

Is a good idea to use App Engine with Python or is it too slow ?

Answer (score 1):

Datastore gets usually take in the low to mid tens of milliseconds, while memcache gets are usually around one to two milliseconds.
So if that's all you are going to use and ignoring the own HTTP request time you can get there.

However App Engine sometimes makes a loading request when he needs to scale and shows the following message:

> This request caused a new process to be started for your application,
>   and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.
>   This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical
>   request for your application.

.

> What is a loading request?
>
> Some requests run slower because App Engine needs to create a new Java
>   Virtual Machine (JVM) to service the request. That kind of request is
>   called a Loading Request. During a loading request, your application
>   undergoes initialization (such as class loading, JIT compiling, etc.)
>   which causes the request to take longer.
>
> Requests have an approximately 60-second deadline, which includes
>   initialization and any additional work your application needs to
>   perform on startup. If your app exceeds this limit, a
>   DeadlineExceededException is returned.
>
> You can find these types of requests in your request logs by filtering
>   on loading_request=1

That would happen only when you scale up, so if you have a constant traffic and you can allow that happening once a while, you are good.

Comment: in fact you can bypass that problem by having empty standby instances already spun up. As those are used, new "real" instances are spun up and the standby instances drained, ready for the next burst.

Comment: I've had good results with Python and Java in terms of latency, but find the loading latency on Java can be problematic.  You _may_ find Go gives you lower latency than Python, at the expense of a less mature API.  You might like to prototype something and use [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-trace) to see a breakdown of the RPCs (e.g. Memcache, Datastore).